# Foundation MonoTouchException NSInternalInconsistencyException SearchBar

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Tengo una app móvil en Xamarin Forms 3.2, la cual funciona bien en Android, sin embargo al ejecutar la build para iOS, compila sin errores, se carga el emulador de iOS y lanza la siguiente excepción:

```
Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInternalInconsistencyException Reason: -[UISearchBar sizeThatFits:] does not support passing non-finite values ({inf, 56})
Native stack trace:
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001078cf6fb __exceptionPreprocess + 331
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001088baac5 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001078cf482 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98
    3   Foundation                          0x00000001071ff927 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 194
    4   UIKitCore                           0x000000010e1ab6b2 -[UISearchBar sizeThatFits:] + 301
    5   marketing_app.iOS                 0x00000001039b1399 xamarin_dyn_objc_msgSend + 217
    6   ???                                 0x000000012eb3f6ae 0x0 + 5078513326
    7   ???                                 0x000000012eb54987 0x0 + 5078600071
```

Dentro de las propiedades, tengo lo siguiente:

[image: Foundation MonoTouchException NSInternalInconsistencyException]

> -[UISearchBar sizeThatFits:] does not support passing non-finite values ({inf, 56})

Me llama la atención que funcione bien en Android y que se rompa en iOS; en fin, efectos de la curva de aprendizaje, por cierto, este el XAML que estoy usando:

```
<SearchBar Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,20,0,0" Placeholder="Search" SearchCommand="{Binding Path=SearchingCommand}" Text="{Binding Path=SearchQuery}"></SearchBar>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo único que faltó fue agregar la propiedad **WidthRequest**

```
<SearchBar Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,20,0,0" Placeholder="Search" SearchCommand="{Binding Path=SearchingCommand}" Text="{Binding Path=SearchQuery}" WidthRequest="50"></SearchBar>
```

¡Ahora funciona perfectamente!

De acuerdo a la documentación:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.searchbar?view=xamarin-forms

La propiedad **WidthRequest**

EN:

> Gets or sets the desired width override of this element.

ES:

> Obtiene o ajusta el ancho deseado de este elemento.